# Win 7 Professional

Tags: images, restore, bootable-media, make, clonezilla

Machine crashed during power outage and failed to boot afterwards.  After running EasyRE and Dell Restore and Recovery, system became bootable and appeared completely intact.  Attempting to image disk with Clonezilla was unsuccessful as SDA1 (Windows partition) was okay but SDA2 (recovery partition from Dell) was reported as having errors and Clonezilla errored out.  Went back and cloned only the SDA1 windows partition (and this is apparently where I made my first mistake) using Beginner mode not Advanced where you can select to save information needed to restore a bootable image.  Mistake number two occurred when I attempted to used Macrium Reflect to copy the Windows partition on the defective disk to a new disk and be bootable.  I thought I followed the directions correctly but apparently didn't.  Anyway, now the previously bootable disk with defects in the Restore partition is in some kind of state I don't know exactly how to describe.  It boots but not correctly.

So my question is, since I have an image of the windows partition, can I restore it to a new disk and make it bootable.  I have not been able to find a solution to do this.  Any assistance would be gratefully appreciated.  I have the data backed up but would very much like to return a disk to the same state it started in less Dell's Restore partition.

Comment: I would run spinrite on the drive...https://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm

Answer (score 0):

if you have the backup of both partition make them bootable again is preatty easy, you need a usb or cd/dvd of windows 7 installation, instead of start installation go to the repair tools and open a terminal;

determinate which disk contain the restored data and you want to make bootable with diskpart:

- list volume

exit from diskpart enter via cmd in the boot folder of the installer and run the following command:

- bootsect /nt60 x: # where x is the device letter of desidered disk

this should be enough if it is not:

- rebuild the bcd info:

  - bootrec /rebuildbcd
- fix mbr (if there have)

  - bootrec /fixmbr
- then fix boot

  - bootrec /fixboot